# The relationship btwn RV-IV and realized skew

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, factor-models, volatility-smile

In studying skew I've been advised to focus on understanding on components that affect it.  One such component that's been recommended to me is the relationship btwn RV-IV and realized skew.  Allegedly, there should be a strong correlation btwn the 2 (skew steepens when RV exceeds implied), but when I regress one on the other, I find no such relationship.  Am I wasting my time?

I also cannot think of some fundamental theory that might explain the relationship.  What would be the theoretical underpinning for why this happens?  Hedgers buying tails?

Comment: Who told you to look for the relationship? Maybe they can offer you relevant literature / data?

Comment: An old contact who I am no longer in touch with.  Unfortunately I cannot reach them